# Is the usage of articles correct in 'The reality is infinitely complex, we all face the life with imperfect understanding'?

Tags: articles

'***The*** reality is infinitely complex, we all face ***the*** life with imperfect understanding.'

The articles is always a struggle for me. If the articles are correct in the above sentence, is there any other mistakes, except the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to convey with the sentence.

Comment: Hard to say without understanding what nuances you're after, but probably the second "the" should be omitted.  The first is more of a judgment call.

Comment: And it's something of a "run-on" sentence -- either break in two or insert the dreaded semicolon.  Or use some other splicing technique.

Comment: To further explain what @HotLicks said, it's a comma splice (two independent clauses joined with a comma), which is not correct. The comma after "complex" should be a period or a semicolon (or maybe a dash).